# No IP address for Virtualbox CentOS image

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I installed CentOS image at Virtualbox, I also configure
ONBOOT=yes at  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

But it still has no IP address. Did I do anything wrong ?
Any suggestions are more than welcome!

[image: config for ifcfg-enp0s3]

Comment: Is the network adapter enabled in the VM settings? Did you configure it as NAT? If so, VirtualBox should assign an IP via its DHCP server.

Comment: yes, networkadpater is configured as bridge. i just found out it works at home, it failed at company network . therefore must be some specific setting at company dhcp config